# Coalesce in where clause with n

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get records based on the given input values. Below is the sample script

```
DECLARE input1 = '001'
DECLARE input2 = '002'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COLUMN1 = COALESCE(input, NULL) OR
COLUMN2 = COALESCE(input2, NULL)// return non-null records, Great

DECLARE input1 = NULL
DECLARE input2 = NULL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COLUMN = COALESCE(input, NULL) // return no records, Problem here
```

I know, `COLUMN = NULL` do not yield any values. Is there a better way, so that NULL input values return null records. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "better" option might be to skip `COALESCE` (or `NVL`) and switch to

```
where column = input
   or (column is null and input is null)
```

Comment: It is not working.         SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN = NULL OR NULL IS NULL) return both null and not null records. Seems like NULL IS NULL returns TRUE

Comment: Right; we can't check whether column `= null`; should be `is null`. Fixed (hopefully); have  a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

> ```sql
> SELECT *
> FROM   table
> WHERE  COLUMN1 = COALESCE(input, NULL)
> OR     COLUMN2 = COALESCE(input2, NULL)
> ```

Will only return results when `COLUMN1 = input OR column2 = input`. It will not return results when both columns are `NULL`.

You will get exactly the same results if you remove the `COALESCE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  COLUMN1 = input
OR     COLUMN2 = input2
```

If you want to check when the `input` is `NULL` and the column value is also `NULL` then you need to use `IS` to compare the values to `NULL` and not `=` like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  COLUMN1 = input                        -- Compare non-NULL values
OR     ( input IS NULL AND COLUMN1 IS NULL )  -- Compare NULL values
OR     COLUMN2 = input2                       -- Compare non-NULL values
OR     ( input2 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL ) -- Compare NULL values
```

Comment: Greate, can you provide me the query, If input is non-null,then return only input non-null values and if input is null then return only input null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return rows with `COLUMN1 is NULL` in case of INPUT is null:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
decode(COLUMN1,input, 1,0) = 1
```

Decode: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE

> In a DECODE function, Oracle considers two nulls to be equivalent

You do not need coalesce in this query from your question:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE COLUMN1 = COALESCE(input, NULL) OR
COLUMN2 = COALESCE(input2, NULL)
```

because `coalesce(input,null)` is equal to simple `input`: coalesce returns first non-null parameter, but your second parameter is null, so it returns

```
input is not NULL | input
-------------------------
input is     NULL | null
```

Comment: There is also partially documented `sys_op_map_nonnull` function, which allows you to write simple `sys_op_map_nonnull(COLUMN1)=sys_op_map_nonnull(INPUT)`, but I'd avoid it since it's not fully supported and documented

Comment: Perhaps LNNVL (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions078.htm) works for you in this case

Comment: @wernfried no, lnnvl doesn't work in such cases. And not for me, but for TS :)